# Adding variable-size labels on top of MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps

I need to add 'balloon'- like markers to my map view. The difficult thing here - these markers  include a variable-length text labels so these balloons have variable sizes. Actually this is exactly what implemented in native google-maps application to show labels. 
Any idea what is optimal  way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement custom overlay. [This article](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html) will be a good start.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but referred article only explains how to place markers on the map. It doesn't answer my question - how to create markers of variable form.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably already using itemized overlays. Your OverlayItem class has a method that returns a Drawable; you can create your own Drawable class that your OverlayItem will return. As for the variable size, you could handle that two ways: either your Drawable could determine its own size (using Paint.measureText() ), or, possibly, you could create a View class to take advantage of a View's ability to figure its own layout, and have your Drawable's draw() method delegate to the View's draw() method. Someone who understands Views better than I do can probably improve on that suggestion.